# R: cut off bars that are too long for the y-axis

Tags: r, histogram

I am making a histogram in R using:

```
hist(SOME_MATRIX[,4],breaks=500,ylim = c(0,1000))
```

But my bars are much taller than the range I gave to the y-axis (0 - 1000). Is there a way using "hist()" to cut off the bars at a maximum value as well?

Comment: Yes it's misleading, but for this plot I am not interested in how long the bars are. I know that they're huge, but that's not what I am trying to show. There are some other things in the plot I am more interested in showing, that is why I want to just cut them at y=1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the caveats discussed in the comments, here's how to cut off the bars at 1000:

```
# Save plot data in an object
x=hist(rnorm(1e5),breaks=50,ylim = c(0,1000))

# Cut off counts at 1000
x$counts[x$counts>1000] = 1000

# Re-plot histogram. Max of y-range is > 1000 to show cutoff.
plot(x, ylim=c(0,1500))
```

[image]